# how to use a jquery ui autocomplete function with wikimedia opensearch api?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, wikimedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=a&limit=10&namespace=0&format=json

the above webpage returns a json array with nested arrays. I just want the second nested array with the titles. How can i use it with jquery ui autocomplete function so that i can use it only with the array of titles.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve What have you tried? What is an example of the resulting data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example. This is based on [Autocomplete | Remote JSONP Datasource](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) example.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/t3ahcdht/

**HTML**

```
<label for="wiki">Wiki:</label>
<input id="wiki">
<button>Go</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#wiki").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(req, resp) {
      $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + req.term + "&limit=10&namespace=0&format=json&callback=?", function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        resp(json[1]);
      })
    }
  });
});
```

This helps address the issue with CORS. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy,

> In computing, the same-origin policy is an important concept in the web application security model. Under the policy, a web browser permits scripts contained in a first web page to access data in a second web page, but only if both web pages have the same origin. An origin is defined as a combination of URI scheme, hostname, and port number. This policy prevents a malicious script on one page from obtaining access to sensitive data on another web page through that page's Document Object Model.

And...

> **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing**
>
> The second technique for relaxing the same-origin policy is standardized under the name Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. This standard extends HTTP with a new Origin request header and a new Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. It allows servers to use a header to explicitly list origins that may request a file or to use a wildcard and allow a file to be requested by any site. Browsers such as Firefox 3.5, Safari 4 and Internet Explorer 10 use this header to allow the cross-origin HTTP requests with XMLHttpRequest that would otherwise have been forbidden by the same-origin policy.

This will allow us to `GET` results from the API with the search term entered by the user and display the results in the autocomplete. Response speed will vary.

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried implement it by dynamically calling html5 datalist element. But the one you suggested looks much better.